# Is it possible to use @Transactional annotation on aspect method instead of service method?

Tags: java, transactions, aop, spring-aop, aspect

I have a micro-service project and I am adding a common feature to every service. For that I wrote code in my common service and it works fine as long as I put @Transactional annotation on every method in service classes of all my services. This is very annoying cause I have to annotate lots of methods in many places. Is it possible to use annotation just once and it will be applied to other methods? Let's say to annotate a method of aspect that intercepts all necessary methods?

I tried to use annotation in my aspect but it does not work...But I still think that there is should be some way to solve this problem.

Comment: If you annotate a class with `@Transactional` it is applied to every method in the class.

Comment: I know, but my team does not want to add this annotation to all classes

Comment: can you provide more info about the structure? This common method is the only one that requires a transaction? If yes why don't you annotate the common method?

Comment: I described the task here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74182708/how-to-use-hibernate-filter-without-transactional

Comment: I did not get any advice, so I created this post

Comment: I need to use hibernate filter but it does not work without transactional. I don't understand why because in every example that Ive seen on stackoverflow nobody mentioned about using this annotation, so I assuming that it should work without somehow but I can't figure out the way to do it.

Comment: Spring AOP can only be applied to Spring beans/components, but not recursively to aspects. Because annotation-driven transactions also utilise Spring AOP, this will not work IMO. You have, however, the option to use `@Transactional` in native AspectJ mode. Because the latter is not limited to Spring beans and also native AspectJ aspects can target other aspects, this might work if done correctly.